# It doesn't hide the answer again

Tags: javascript

I went to girlswhogeek.com. Their code is what I'm looking for since it hides first the element then when you click the button it will show the answer. It's just that it doesn't hide the answer again.

Here's their code:

```
<p><a href="#">What price are your apples?</a><br>
<span id="answer1" style="display:none;">Our apples are 30 pence 
each...</span></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showStuff(id) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display= 'block';
}
function hideStuff(id) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
}
</script>
```

Comment: When do you want to hide it again ?

Comment: How are `hideStuff` and `showStuff` called? When you try to hide it do you see any error in the console?

Comment: Please show how you call these functions.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in one function `toggleStuff` like:-

```js
function toggleStuff(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'block') {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#" onclick="toggleStuff('answer1'); return false;">What price are your apples?</a><br><br>
  <span id="answer1" style="display: none;">Our apples are 30 pence each. If you buy 10 or more we can sell them at a discounted bulk rate of 25 pence each.</span></p>
```

Comment: What if I also want to add image on the answer? How can I hide it?

Comment: If the image is inside same span id `answer1` then it would be automatically hidden along with span, else you will need to pass additional `id` to `toggleStuff` function like `toggleStuff('answer1', 'image1')` and then modify the code to include the new id like `function toggleStuff(id1, id2)` and then hide them individually.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how these are called such as  `<a id="btnID" onclick="showStuff('btnID')>Button</a>`... etc.

If there are two buttons (or elements of your choice) then make sure an onclick event is show for one and hide for the other. If only using one you might need an if statement based on if it is displayed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example with you code...code looks right you might have issue with calling the method wrong

```js
function showStuff(id) {
alert(id);
document.getElementById(id).style.display= 'block';
}
function hideStuff(id) {
alert(id);
document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="showStuff('test')" value="show"/>
<input type="button" onclick="hideStuff('test')" value="hide"/>
<div id="test">sample div</div>
```